# @JvmDefault not found sourceCompatibility/targetCompatibility assigned by project variable

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, default-method, jvm-default

I want to provide default implementation for method in my Kotlin interface:

```
interface INavItem : Comparable<INavItem> {

    val order: Int

    @JvmDefault
    override fun compareTo(other: INavItem): Int = order.compareTo(other.order)
}
```

but `@JvmDefault` highlighted with error:

> '@JvmDefault' is only supported since JVM target 1.8. Recompile with '-jvm-target 1.8

---

JVM target 1.8 setting is present in *root project* build file:

```
project.ext {
    javaVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    // other properties
}
```

and I use it inside of *module* build file:

```
android {

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility rootProject.ext.javaVersion
        targetCompatibility rootProject.ext.javaVersion
    }
    // ...
}
```

Note: Java 8 features (lambdas, etc...) are available in java sources.

---

Is exist any way to assign `source/targetCompatibility` by variables visible for Kotlin lint?

Comment: The sourceCompatibilty option is an option that affects the Java compiler. Kotlin has separate options, and you aren't setting those.

Comment: @yole you need to share link to original question if you mark my question as duplicate

Comment: I did. See the top of the question.

Comment: @yole I missed it. Thank you